# Understanding negative numbers in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm just getting my head around recursion in javascript using the book Eloquent Javascript but don't fully understand what is happening to the negative number (-1) in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/greenhulk01/kg5ton1t/

```
function isEven(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (n < 0) {

        return isEven(-n);
    } else {
        return isEven(n - 2);
    }
};

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → false
```

I understand everything that is going on in this recursion except for how "return isEven(-n);" is being handled. Using console.log i can see it is returned as undefined so not sure why it is caught by the false statement.

Any pointers to help my understanding would be really appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: `undefined` evaluates to `false` most of the time. So does `0`, or the empty string.

Comment: why do you think it returned "undefined" if you code indicates that `console.log(isEven(-1));` returned `false`?

Comment: Please don't ever use that actual code to check whether numbers are even. It may be useful as an example of recursion, but it's a terrible way of performing that test.

Comment: I wouldn't. It is just used in the book as an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isEven(-n) just takes advantage of the fact that if -n is even, n is even, too. So basically  isEven(-10) calls isEven(10)

BTW: Did you try isEven(1.5)? I'd expect false, but I'd guess you'd get a stack overflow. I'd write this as

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return isEven(-n);
  }
  if (n >= 2) {
    return isEven(n - 2);
  }
  return n == 0;
};
```

BTW 2: Without using recursion, you could just write

```
function isEven(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all for taking the time to respond. Really helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. That is how I would do it normally - only doing it with recursion as the book asks you to.